# SwiftUI - Delete navigation back button title

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar

I want to delete the "Back" from the image below.

https://pasteboard.co/J8s2PTh.png

In scene delegate file, I customize the navigation back button, but i am trying to get rid of "Back" word.

```
 fileprivate func  setupAppearance(){
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: ImageText.leftArrow.string)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: ImageText.leftArrow.string)

}
```